# How to enable JMX in Weblogic to set any attribute through WLST

Tags: python, weblogic12c, wlst

I am getting following error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The requested
>   attribute is not exposed through JMX: setEnabled

How I can solve this issue.

Here is the set of command which I had tried in WLST (Weblogic Scripting Tool).

```
wls:/MiCommApp/serverConfig> cd('/Servers/'  'AdminServer' '/SSL/' 'AdminServer' )
wls:/MiCommApp/serverConfig/Servers/AdminServer/SSL/AdminServer> cmo.setEnabled(true)
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
        at weblogic.management.jmx.ExceptionMapper.matchJMXException(ExceptionMapper.java:74)
        at weblogic.management.jmx.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:508)
        at weblogic.management.jmx.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:382)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.setEnabled(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The requested attribute
is not exposed through JMX: setEnabled
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have do go edit mode before altering setting any instance variables by using this commands `edit()` & `startEdit()`

WLST prompt `!>` signified we are in edit mode.

```
wls:/myBeaDir/serverConfig/Servers/MiCommApp/SSL/MiCommApp> edit()
Location changed to edit tree. This is a writable tree with
DomainMBean as the root. To make changes you will need to start
an edit session via startEdit().

For more help, use help('edit')

wls:/myBeaDir/edit> startEdit()
Starting an edit session ...
Started edit session, please be sure to save and activate your
changes once you are done.
wls:/myBeaDir/edit !> cd('/Servers/'  'MiCommApp' '/SSL/' 'MiCommApp' )
wls:/myBeaDir/edit/Servers/MiCommApp/SSL/MiCommApp !>
```