# How to expose JVM property thorough JMX for Weblogic SSL

Tags: java, python, ssl, weblogic12c, wlst

I am doing WLST scripting, where I supposed to enable SSL Listen port. I am getting error as described in this Q&A topic.

[How to enable JMX in Weblogic to set any attribute through WLST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377947/how-to-enable-jmx-in-weblogic-to-set-any-attribute-through-wlst)

I had run following WLST (Weblogic Scripting Tool).

```
cd('/Servers/'  'MiCommApp' '/SSL/' 'MiCommApp' )
cmo.setEnabled(true)
```

I had enabled JMX by setting following JVM properties through server start tab in Weblogic Console.

> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

But still I am facing the same problem saying

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The requested
>   attribute is not exposed through JMX: setEnabled

How I can expose required attribute through JMX.

Comment: We should be in editing mode we have to use `edit()` & `startEdit()` before editing any `WLST` present tree variable using `cmo.set_()`. cmo stands for Current Management Object. And we should be in admin login using `connect( 'adminUser', 'adminPasswd', 't3://wl_server:__admin_port__')` command. Also this command turns WLST offline mode to specific server's connected mode.

Comment: Once editing is done, we could say `save()` & `activate()`