# Deploying from netbeans Java Web Application to Weblogic server error

Tags: java, netbeans, weblogic

I have a java web application that I'm trying to deploy to a WebLogic server.

The server is set to the Oracle WebLogic Server. This server is set up correctly with the correct host name, port and user credentials.

When I deploy the application, I get the following error.

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\myWebApp -Dnb.internal.action.name=redeploy -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=false -DforceRedeploy=true -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\myWebApp run-deploy
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Building jar: C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myWebApp\dist\myWebApp.war
Distributing C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myWebApp\dist\myWebApp.war
Deploying C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myWebApp\dist\myWebApp.war
Deployment failed. The message was: com.bea:Name=AdminServer,Type=Server:DynamicallyCreated
C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myWebApp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1066: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 18 seconds)
```

There are no entries in the server log. Is there anything else that needs to be changed.

We have been getting around this issue by FTPing the WAR file to the VM and updating the deployment. We would like to do it from within Netbeans so that the version control will work correctly.

Netbeans 8.2

Java 1.8 (on the development machine and the WebLogic VM)

WebLogic 11g (10.3.6.0)

**UPDATE**

This is the contents of the netbeans log.

```
WARNING [org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager]: use of system property netbeans.user has been obsoleted in favor of InstalledFileLocator/Places at org.netbeans.modules.java.api.common.project.BaseActionProvider.verifyUserPropertiesFile(BaseActionProvider.java:2322)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager]
javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException: com.bea:Name=AdminServer,Type=Server:DynamicallyCreated
    at weblogic.management.jmx.modelmbean.WLSModelMBean.getPropertyDescriptorForAttribute(WLSModelMBean.java:1420)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.getPropertyDescriptor(SecurityInterceptor.java:890)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.checkGetSecurity(SecurityInterceptor.java:579)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.getAttribute(SecurityInterceptor.java:298)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServer.java:279)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.internal.ManagedMBeanServerConnection.getAttribute(ManagedMBeanServerConnection.java:304)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.internal.FederatedMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(FederatedMBeanServerInterceptor.java:310)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$12.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:324)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXContextInterceptor.getAttribute(JMXContextInterceptor.java:157)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$12.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:324)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$12.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:324)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.getAttribute(SecurityInterceptor.java:299)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServer.java:279)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder$5$1.run(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder$5.run(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:324)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.getAttribute(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:319)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1403)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:72)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1264)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1366)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:600)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:667)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: The requested attribute is not exposed through JMX: isDynamicallyCreated: com.bea:Name=AdminServer,Type=Server:DynamicallyCreated
    at weblogic.management.jmx.ExceptionMapper.matchJMXException(ExceptionMapper.java:75)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:520)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:390)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.isDynamicallyCreated(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.deploy.utils.ApplicationUtils.isDynamicClusterServer(ApplicationUtils.java:1434)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache.getTargetsFromDomain(TargetCache.java:83)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache.getTypedMBeans(TargetCache.java:57)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.MBeanCache.getMBeans(MBeanCache.java:68)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache.getTargets(TargetCache.java:180)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache.getTargets(TargetCache.java:96)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache.getTargets(TargetCache.java:144)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.getServers(ServerConnectionImpl.java:683)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.getBaseTargets(ServerConnectionImpl.java:531)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.getTargets(ServerConnectionImpl.java:575)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getTargets(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:520)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getTargets(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:512)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getTargets(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:545)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager.translateTargets(WLDeploymentManager.java:909)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager.access$300(WLDeploymentManager.java:132)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager$4.execute(WLDeploymentManager.java:543)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager$4.execute(WLDeploymentManager.java:538)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager$3.call(WLDeploymentManager.java:387)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.WLConnectionSupport.executeAction(WLConnectionSupport.java:112)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager.executeAction(WLDeploymentManager.java:374)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager.getAvailableModules(WLDeploymentManager.java:538)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.getAvailableTMIDsMap(TargetServer.java:443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.processLastTargetModules(TargetServer.java:480)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.init(TargetServer.java:195)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.deploy(TargetServer.java:630)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:246)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:166)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:111)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager]
javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException: com.bea:Name=AdminServer,Type=Server:DynamicallyCreated
    at weblogic.management.jmx.modelmbean.WLSModelMBean.getPropertyDescriptorForAttribute(WLSModelMBean.java:1420)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.getPropertyDescriptor(SecurityInterceptor.java:890)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.checkGetSecurity(SecurityInterceptor.java:579)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.getAttribute(SecurityInterceptor.java:298)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServer.java:279)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.internal.ManagedMBeanServerConnection.getAttribute(ManagedMBeanServerConnection.java:304)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.internal.FederatedMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(FederatedMBeanServerInterceptor.java:310)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$12.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:324)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXContextInterceptor.getAttribute(JMXContextInterceptor.java:157)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$12.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:324)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$12.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:324)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.getAttribute(SecurityInterceptor.java:299)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServer.java:279)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder$5$1.run(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder$5.run(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:324)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.getAttribute(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:319)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1403)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:72)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1264)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1366)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:600)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:667)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: The requested attribute is not exposed through JMX: isDynamicallyCreated: com.bea:Name=AdminServer,Type=Server:DynamicallyCreated
    at weblogic.management.jmx.ExceptionMapper.matchJMXException(ExceptionMapper.java:75)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:520)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:390)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.isDynamicallyCreated(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.deploy.utils.ApplicationUtils.isDynamicClusterServer(ApplicationUtils.java:1434)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache.getTargetsFromDomain(TargetCache.java:83)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache.getTypedMBeans(TargetCache.java:57)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.MBeanCache.getMBeans(MBeanCache.java:68)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache.getTargets(TargetCache.java:180)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache.getTargets(TargetCache.java:96)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache.getTargets(TargetCache.java:144)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.getServers(ServerConnectionImpl.java:683)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.getBaseTargets(ServerConnectionImpl.java:531)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.getTargets(ServerConnectionImpl.java:575)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getTargets(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:520)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getTargets(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:512)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getTargets(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:545)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager.translateTargets(WLDeploymentManager.java:909)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager.access$300(WLDeploymentManager.java:132)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager$4.execute(WLDeploymentManager.java:543)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager$4.execute(WLDeploymentManager.java:538)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager$3.call(WLDeploymentManager.java:387)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.WLConnectionSupport.executeAction(WLConnectionSupport.java:112)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager.executeAction(WLDeploymentManager.java:374)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLDeploymentManager.getAvailableModules(WLDeploymentManager.java:538)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.deploy.WLTargetModuleIDResolver.lookupTargetModuleID(WLTargetModuleIDResolver.java:80)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.checkUndeployForSharedReferences(TargetServer.java:374)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.checkUndeployForSharedReferences(TargetServer.java:347)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.processLastTargetModules(TargetServer.java:519)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.init(TargetServer.java:195)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer.deploy(TargetServer.java:630)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:246)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:166)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:111)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
WARNING [org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager]: use of system property netbeans.user has been obsoleted in favor of InstalledFileLocator/Places at org.netbeans.processtreekiller.ProcessTreeKiller$Windows.<clinit>(ProcessTreeKiller.java:187)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.TargetServer]: Cannot incrementally deploy to more than one target
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment]
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:259)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:166)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:111)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

Comment: A couple of questions: [1] Is the problem specific to only this project/application? i.e. Can you successfully deploy other projects/applications to your WebLogic server from within NetBeans? [2] I'm surprised there is nothing in server log. Perhaps check the NetBeans log? Try this: (a) Open the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) and note the content at EOF. (b) Repeat the deployment. (c) Assuming it fails, update your question with anything that was written to the NetBeans log as a result of the attempted deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @skomisa. [1] This is the only project that i deploy to WebLogic, so i'm not sure if this is specific to this application or not. [2] I've included the NetBeans log. I'll try find the solution for it.

Comment: OK. [1] I am not familiar with WebLogic at all, but it looks like your root problem is: `The requested attribute is not exposed through JMX: isDynamicallyCreated`. Maybe this SO question is relevant and helpful?... [How to enable JMX in Weblogic to set any attribute through WLST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41377947/2985643). [2] Is the WebLogic server definitely running?

Comment: I had similar problem, something wrong with deploy. uninstall application, restart weblogic, deploy some simple application, test it and then deploy again your app.